# Asp.net MVC: upload multiple image files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, image-uploading

is there a good example of how to upload multiple image files in asp.net mvc? I know we can use HttpPostedFileBase to upload one file. Is there a way to upload multiple files by clicking one button?

I used file upload in ajaxtoolbox in webform before and like how it works. Is there a similar way in MVC? or, is there a existing control that can do this well? free control is better, but it is ok even it costs some $.

Thanks

Comment: we used http://www.plupload.com/ at my last job for multiple uploads

Comment: is there a simple example of how to use it in asp.net MVC? thanks.

Comment: I don't have access to that code base anymore.  Here is an example I found googling https://pluploadmvc4demo.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this [jQuery plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

just include plugin js files, create tag:

```
<input type='file' multiple id='fileUpload' name="files[]" data-url="@Url.Action("Upload","Home")" />
```

(Except IE9 it is not allowing select multiple files in select dialog)

Add some JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileUpload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In controller action just check Request.Files and do whatever you want. 
Here is a good [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki)

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload() 
{
    foreach (var file in Request.Files)
    {
        if(file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + file.FileName));
        }
    }

    return Json(new { result = true });
}
```

Comment: using this plugin, a basic example can be found here : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Answer (score 29):

You could implement an action with `POST` http verb to that receive a collection of `HttpPostedFileBase` and save all files, for sample:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) 
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Update/" + file.FileName));
    }

    return View();
}
```

Alternatively, you could read `Request.Files` and do the same job,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload() 
{
    foreach (var file in Request.Files)
    {
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Update/" + file.FileName));
    }

    return View();
}
```

### See Also

- [Single File Upload to Multiple File Upload in MVC](http://www.itorian.com/2014/03/single-file-upload-to-multiple-file.html)
- [Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, it really helped me

Comment: I tried to upload 396 csv files and it's working fine but when I tried to upload 484 files it's not working anymore what I am missing? I already edited the web.config based  on this [site](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/upload-large-files-asp-net-radasyncupload)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this one. https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

```
<input type="file" name="file" class="multiple" /> 

[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Upload()  
{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
          foreach(var file in Request.Files) {  }
    }

    return View(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the basic bits required for file uploads

Notice keyword: **multiple** in input element AND
**multipart** in form element

### HTML Side

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyUpload", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { 
    <input type="file" name="myFiles" multiple />
    <button class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>   
}
```

---

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> myFiles)
{
    foreach (var file in myFiles)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //handle files;
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```